# angular 2 route param into data

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple route with 1 parameter:

```
{
    path: 'item/:id',
    component: ItemComponent,
    data: {title: 'Item detail'}
}
```

I'm setting page title using data title property in main AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title: string;

    ngOnInit() {
         this.router.events
         .. parse it
         .subscribe((event) => {
                this.title = event['title'];
         });
    }
}
```

Then I'm just displaying it in AppComponent template:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

The problem is if I want to have dynamic title like `"Item detail #name(:id)"`. Is there any way how can I add e.g. route param (:id) or variable into data title property? Something like

```
{
    path: 'item/:id',
    component: ItemComponent,
    data: {title: 'Item detail #' + :id }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. But you can keep the `data.title` param as a "blueprint" and do a search/replace from within the component.

Comment: Is it possible to replace it within ItemComponent?

Comment: Yup. I posted an answer with some code. Any specific reason why you're using `router.events` to extract the route data/params? (instead of just `route.data` and `route.params`)

Comment: Router events are used for every route change.

Comment: Sure, but in your case you don't want to watch ALL router events, you just want to extract specific route properties and these properties are directly available on `ActivatedRoute(.snapshot)`.

Comment: No, it will not work. I was following this code -> https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

Comment: Alright. :) I'm not saying it won't work, was just curious why you chose this implementation.

Comment: I also tried your code and it didn't work (I mean title change on every route change not id replacing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, you could keep the `data.title` param as a blueprint and replace the dynamic part from within the component.

Route declaration:

```ts
{
  path: 'item/:id',
  component: ItemComponent,
  data: { title: 'Item detail [id]' }
}
```

In `data.title`, I wrote `[id]` to make replacement easier but feel free to use whatever symbols you'd like to delimitate the string to replace.

Then, in the component:

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  title: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const titlePattern = this.route.snapshot.data['title'];
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.title = titlePattern.replace('[id]', id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but it would not make any sense replacing it inside AppComponent because there might be xx routes with same pattern. Would be better if I change it inside each FeatureComponent so I decided to create a service for it.